# How can I toggle the document between print and view mode?

Tags: conditionals, printing

Is there a possibility to set a key into my header which defines the desired output of my document? I can imagine three modes:

1. Print (black and white)
2. Print (colored)
3. PDF for display view

With `ifthen` it should be easy to define different commands for those modes or to insert blank pages and so on. Here are some examples for the use:

- Blank pages for print
- Color on/off
- Color definition in RGB (PDF) or CMYK (print)
- ignoring hyperrefs
- printing todos
- and so on...

This switch could be something like the `draft` mode in `scrreprt`. Or maybe a single mark like `\setcustomswitch{mode=printColored %,printBW,PDF}` (command invented by me).

Comment: For hyper links, `hyperref` offers `ocgcolorlinks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you list can for the most part be achieved using options to the packages that supply the functionality you want to modify. For example pass option `gray` or `cmyk` to the xcolor package to switch the color space. Likewise, hyperref has options to modify the behavior of hyperlinks in the document.

Make a package for each of the desired states of your document, i.e., `mydoc-print.sty` and `mydoc-online.sty` and switch between the two.

A more interesting way to generate a document that displays in color but prints in black and white is to use the [ocg-p](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) package and define commands that generate black and white in the printed optional contents group and colored output in the visible optional contents group.

**Edit:**

Here is an example with conditionals to change the output of the document. I still think you would be better off collecting the settings and stylings in a custom package for each of the intended outputs

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifcolor
\newif\ifonline

\onlinetrue % toggle true/false to change between cmyk/rgb
\colortrue  % change to grayscale

\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifcolor
    \ifonline
        \selectcolormodel{rgb}%
    \else
        \selectcolormodel{cmyk}%
    \fi
\else
    \selectcolormodel{gray}%
\fi

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First suggestion: I am using several functions like those mentioned, but I don't like to search around in all packages and to have `%comment for printing` all over the place. Second suggestion: I don't like custom packages as they make everything less portable. Third suggestion: I'll have a look on `ocg-p` tomorrow. Isn*t there any possibility to set a mark which can be read by `ifthen`. For example I'm checking for `xetex` or not and switching my preamble for each case. Would be really handy.

Comment: `ocg-p` is an interesting package. But not what I want. It would make a lot of efforts to layer all parts in my document and the viewer needs the possibility for that. Their should be a possibility to clearly separate print and web version.

Comment: Your edit shows exactly what I wanted. I'm going to try both, conditional and custom package. But very interesting input this `\newif\ifcolor` command. Thanks. I suggest the `ifthen` package is needed for your MWE?

Comment: `\newif` is a TeX primitive and does not rely on the `ifthen` package. The `ifthen` package has the `\newboolean` command which you can use if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @Martin Heller, there is a good solution. Here are some examples for the use of those conditionals. Maybe, they serve somebody else, too.

Defining the bools:

At top of the `header.txt`

```
\newif\ifcolor %bool for toggling color mode to b/w mode
\newif\ifprint %bool fot toggling web mode to print mode

\colortrue
%\colorfalse
%\printtrue
\printfalse
```

Defining commands such as logos (real black for printing instead of grey scale):

```
\newcommand{\Logo}{\ifcolor ... \else ... \fi}
```

General use of colors with `xcolor`:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{aBlueSample}{cmyk}{1.00, 0.80, 0.00, 0.10}
\ifcolor
\ifprint\selectcolormodel{cmyk}%
\else\selectcolormodel{rgb}\fi
\else\selectcolormodel{gray}\fi
```

Handling hyperlinks:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\ifprint\ifcolor\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, urlcolor=blue}\else\hypersetup{hidelinks}\fi\fi
```

Example of blank pages used after `\begin{document}`:

```
\ifprint\cleardoublestandardpage\fi
```

Or blank pages in general:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\ifprint\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}\else\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}\fi
```