# Add to latexmk black&white output version

Tags: latexmk

I want to generate a colored and a black & white version of my latex document. Is it possible to configure latexmk via a latexmkrc file to do so?

Output folder should contain two pdf files.

Alternatively, does there a PDF-Viewer exist, which allow to preview the document in black & white?

Comment: I do not know `latexmkrc` files but maybe my answer here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122395) is of interest. I always set my conditional manually and run LaTeX again. You could do a `bw.tex` and a `color.tex` both including `\newif\ifcolor
\colortrue
%\colorfalse
\input{main.tex}` (and vice versa) and than you configure something like `pdflatex bw.tex color.tex` and get two PDFs at once.

Answer (score 1):

Write a file called `bw.cfg` and containing

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
```

and modify your main file to have

```
\InputIfFileExists{bw.cfg}{}{}
```

before the call to `xcolor`. For printing in colors just rename the file.

Full test document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\InputIfFileExists{bw.cfg}{}{}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Black \textcolor{red}{Red}
\textcolor{blue}{Blue}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output when `latexmk -g -pdf testcolor` is run and the configuration file is found.

[image]

Upon renaming `bw.cfg` to `bw.cfg-disabled` the output is

[image]

Note the `-g` option to force full compilation. You need it only when changing the color option, of course.

You can use the `-jobname` option to make `latexmk` produce a differently named PDF file. A shell script doing the two runs of `latexmk` (with renaming of the `.cfg` file) is the easiest way to get two PDF files.